# Perl HTML:TreeBuilder tag not equal to

Tags: regex, perl, html-treebuilder

I am using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) in order to extract data from html file. What I need to do is to:

```
$div->look_down(_tag => 'a', 'href' !=> 'index.html')
```

So I am searching for a href that is not equal to 'index.html' and one other tag but obviously `!=>` is not proper command for `HTML::TreeBuilder`.
How can I achieve something like that? Can I use regular expression?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "not equal", but you can use a regex that matches anything but that string, like this

```
$div->look_down( _tag => 'a', href => qr/\A(?!index\.html\z)/i )
```

or you could write a subroutine that makes the check

```
$div->look_down( _tag => 'a', sub { lc $_[0]->attr('href') ne 'index.html' } )
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. Can I use something like: `$div->look_down(_tag => 'a', href => qr/\A(?!index\.html && ?!somethingelse\.html\z)/)` for multiple condition?

Comment: @Lenny: You can add as many conditions as you like, so for instance `$div->look_down(_tag => 'a', class => 'myclass', href => qr/\A(?!index\.html\z)/i)` but if you have any subroutine checks then put them last as they are the slowest.